# C++ class,object and return

Tags: c++, class, object, parameters, return

I have few questions about my code, please answer them.I'm beginner in C++.
I have made this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Enemy{
    public:
        string enemy(string n,int h,int d){
            name = n;
            hp = h;
            dmg = d;
            cout << "Enemy name: " << n << "   ";
            cout << "Hit Points: " << h << "   ";
            cout << "Damage: " << d;
        }
    private:
        string name;
        int hp;
        int dmg;
};

int main(){

    Enemy enemy1;

    enemy1.enemy("Wolf",10,2);
}
```

When I build and run it I get this:

```
Enemy name: Wolf   Hit Points: 10   Damage: 2
```

Should I use return in `enemy function`?If I use return how to print out `name,hp and dmg`?

Why I can't make second object like Enemy enemy2; and to print out second enemy like

```
enemy2.enemy("Blal","324","32");?
```

How I can make this same function but for a player like Player name: `Hit Points`: `Damage:` and how could I ask a user for his name and enter it in Player name:.

I know these question are dumb, but please answer them and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour as the member function `enemy()` flows of the end of the function without returning a `string`. Change the return type to `void` unless there is some value to report to the caller, in this case it appears not.

Comment: Why can't you make a second object like Enemy enemy2?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down a bit:

> Should I use return in enemy function?

I believe your compiler warned you about that. Why? Let's look at `enemy` function signature:

```
string enemy(string n,int h,int d){
```

So it takes one `string` and two `int`s, and is supposed to return a `string`. You don't return anything, though!

> If I use return how to print out name,hp and dmg?

Exactly the same you do it in your function, except you will need to make that all into one string. It's easiest to do it using a `stringstream`.

```
// remember to
#include <sstream>

string enemy(string n,int h,int d) {
   // initialize variables
   // ...
   std::stringstream s;
   s << "Enemy name: " << n << "   ";
   s << "Hit Points: " << h << "   ";
   s << "Damage: " << d;
   // here we return the data
   return s.str();
}
```

However, this is not the proper way to do it. It looks like you're trying to create a *constructor*. I don't want to write all the code for you, but instead I want you to:

1. Read about constructors, what they are, and how to write them
2. Split the `enemy` function into two parts: initialization and printing it out.
3. Put the first part in a constructor and the second part in either `tostring()` function, or (better) *stream output operator* (`<<`).

As for "how could I ask a user for his name and enter it in Player name", stream extraction operator might be good for that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use return unless you want to return data - so in this case either set the return type to void, or update the function to be a constructor (which is probably what you're intending here).